# CAS Authentication

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, cas

**exception:**

javax.servlet.ServletException: 
       org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: 
        The supplied service app url is not authorized to          use CAS proxy authentication

**root cause:**
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: 
        The supplied service appurl is not authorized to use CAS proxy authentication.
     I am getting above Exception while authenticating my application through cas

Comment: You'll need to show come code if you want anybody to be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

Well, the stacktrace clearly shows that your application do not have authorization to use CAS. Try to register it on service register of the CAS. If your CAS already have JDBC service to store the service registry, access service register in the services context (something like https://youtcasserver.com/services). Or if you are going to have XML based in memory service registry, add it to your deployerConfigContext.xml.

refer to following URL for configuring service registry:

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuring when you are on CAS 3.X or
http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.0/installation/Service-Management.html when you are on CAS 4.0